# How to search error by @error.message in datadog

Tags: datadog

I was attempting to create a Datadog error monitor to count occurrences where @error.message contains the text 'An error occurred when adding frequent card' However, it seems that Datadog's search query doesn't provide an option for ambiguous searches. Using @error.message: 'An error occurred when adding frequent card with ID: ABCDE' yields results, but I want to search for cases where @error.message contains that text without requiring an exact match. How can I perform this type of search?

I tried with regex and wildcard * but not working,
I expect to be able to create search query in datadog to filter out error.message that contain text "An error occurred when adding frequent card"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using (double or single) quotes around a text doesn't allow using wildcards indeed, instead it'll search for the `*` character. You can instead use the wildcard to replace spaces and remove the double quotes, e.g.:

```
@error.message:An*error*occurred*when*adding*frequent*card*with*ID\:*
```

[Example of searching error message with wildcard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nodD1.png)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If you want more accurate results, you can use "\ " instead of "*" in the query.